# How to fix 'undefined method `get_aliases' for #<Elasticsearch::API::Indices::IndicesClient:0x00007fc31b6ed558>'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, searchkick

I'm trying to set up ElasticSearch with the Searchkick gem on a Ruby on Rails (5.2.2) project. I'm following the setup instructions from https://github.com/ankane/searchkick but I'm getting the following error when I try adding data to the search index (running `Modelname.reindex` in the rails console).

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `get_aliases' for # 
<Elasticsearch::API::Indices::IndicesClient:0x00007fc31b6ed558>
Did you mean?  get_alias
from /Users/XXXX/.rbenv/versions/2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/searchkick-3.1.2/lib/searchkick/index.rb:104:in `all_indices'
```

I've tried uninstalling ElasticSearch and the Searchkick gem and reinstalling. And I've also tried changing get_aliases to get_alias in the index.rb file.

`Modelname.reindex` should allow me to add data to the search index.

Comment: Please confirm your `elasticsearch-ruby` version it appears `get_aliases` was removed in 6.3.0 but exists in all versions prior to that

Comment: Hi, my version was 6.3.0, and I have just downgraded it to 6.2.0 as suggested by Dausuul. Seems to have fixed this problem but I'm running into another issue now (Failed to open TCP connection to localhost:9200).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just ran into the same issue. It seems to be a problem with Searchkick relying on something that was removed from Elasticsearch in the latest version of the Elasticsearch gem (which was released literally 10 hours ago).

Hopefully it will be fixed soon, but if you really need it to work right now, putting this in your Gemfile should fix it:

```
gem 'elasticsearch', '~> 6.2.0'
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I downgraded to 6.2.0 and that fixed it. I'm running into `Failed to open TCP connection to localhost:9200` now but that's a different issue.

Comment: If you don't mind to explain I'm wondering how you found out that this was the issue. I'm very new in dev and I'd love to understand what process you went through to find the root cause of this. Thanks a ton for your help.

Comment: Automated testing.

The app I work on has a very extensive test suite. Every so often, I run "bundle update" to keep all my gems current. Then I run the test suite to make sure nothing broke. One of the tests started failing after my most recent update; since the error pointed me to Elasticsearch, it was a reasonable guess that was the gem to look at.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not using Searchkick and just ran into this issue.

The method *get_aliases* got renamed in the current Version of the elasticsearch gem. 
You should use *get_alias* instead.